# How to process break an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to use a double array. But I still fail to do it. This what I did.

```
Folder = "D:\folder"
Name = ['gadfg5', '546sfdgh']
Ver = [None, 'hhdt5463']
    for dn in Name :
        for dr in Ver :
            if dr is None:
                Default = "asbsda"
                Path = os.path.join(Folder, Default)
                print(Path)
            else:
                Path = os.path.join(Folder, dr, dn)
                print(Path)
```

it return this:

```
D:\folder\gadfg5\asbsda
D:\folder\gadfg5\asbsda
D:\folder\gadfg5\asbsda
D:\folder\546sfdgh\hhdt5463
```

But my expectation of the output is:

```
D:\folder\gadfg5\asbsda
D:\folder\546sfdgh\hhdt5463
```

Anyone can give me advice or idea please. Thank you.

Comment: What is "DriverDefault"? Shoudn't it be "Default'?

Comment: Please post the actual code you used and its actual output.

The code you posted will not produce what you said it did.

Comment: This code has some errors, and even after fixing them - this is not the output it gives... Please [edit] your question to include a valid [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the output of the code you posted is:

```
D:\Folder\asbsda
D:\Folder\hhdt5463\gadfg5
D:\Folder\asbsda
D:\Folder\hhdt5463\546sfdgh
```

it is expected because you iterate through both arrays that has 2 elements each and that gives 4 combinations:

`gadfg5 & None`

`gadfg5 & hhdt5463`

`546sfdgh & None`

`546sfdgh & hhdt5463`

I hope you understand.

To get the desired result try using zip:

```
Folder = "D:\Folder"
Name = ['gadfg5', '546sfdgh']
Ver = [None, 'hhdt5463']
for dn, dr in zip(Name, Ver): # get each element of Name and Ver in sequence
    if dr is None:
        Default = "asbsda"
        Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, Default)
        print(Path)
    else:
        Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, dr)
        print(Path)
```

Zip combines each element of each of the array to a tuple and return an array of tuples to iterate through, `zip([a,b,c], [1,2,3]) -> [(a,1),(b,2),(c,3)]`

or enumerate:

```
Folder = "D:\Folder"
Name = ['gadfg5', '546sfdgh']
Ver = [None, 'hhdt5463']
for idx, dn in enumerate(Name): # get index and element of Name
    if Ver[idx] is None:
        Default = "asbsda"
        Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, Default)
        print(Path)
    else:
        Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, Ver[idx])
        print(Path)
```

enumerate adds a counter to your iterable and gives you each element of the array with its index.

output:

```
D:\Folder\gadfg5\asbsda
D:\Folder\546sfdgh\hhdt5463
```

Comment: Hi @Abhi_J I’ve another case which is ‘Ver=[None, None] and the ‘Default={“asbsda”, “gksjdj”} could please helpe me give an idea about this case. Thanks before :)

Comment: Hi @Cheries sure happy to help, but could you ask this as a new question with a code you tried, else we might get downvoted due to community rules.

Comment: @Cheries I can tell you how to proceed. Try by saving your default values to a list and use `zip` or `enumerate` on all three lists.

Comment: Hi @Abhi_J okay Buddy. I will create a new question. Thank you

Comment: hi @Abhi_J here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66595328/11076819
Please check it out. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You need to `zip` the two lists so that you cycle through them both simultaneously, as in the following code. You also had some errors in your code which I took the liberty to correct:

```
import os;
Folder = r"D:\folder"
Name = ['gadfg5', '546sfdgh']
Ver = [None, 'hhdt5463']
for dn,dr in zip(Name,Ver) :
        if dr is None:
            Default = "asbsda"
            Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, Default)
            print(Path)
        else:
            Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, dr)
            print(Path)
```

The output is:

```
D:\folder/gadfg5/asbsda
D:\folder/546sfdgh/hhdt5463
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected output, it seems you need to iterate over the elements of the two lists in a pairwise fashion and you can use `zip()` for that:

```
for dn, dr in zip(Name, Ver):
    if dr is None:
        Default = "asbsda"
        Path = os.path.join(Folder, Default)
        print(Path)
    else:
        Path = os.path.join(Folder, dr, dn)
        print(Path)
```

Output:

```
D:\folder\asbsda
D:\folder\hhdt5463\546sfdgh
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to reduce the complexity, by replacing all `None` values in `Ver` first:

```
Folder = "D:/folder"
Name = ['gadfg5', '546sfdgh']
Ver = [None, 'hhdt5463']

# Replace all Nones in Ver with default value
Ver = [v if v else 'defaultPath' for v in Ver]

allPaths = list(zip(Name, Ver))

for pth in allPaths:
    print(os.path.join(Folder, *pth))
```

Out:

```
D:\folder\gadfg5\defaultPath
D:\folder\546sfdgh\hhdt5463
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a single loop.

We go through the array and see if the element in question is none, if so we replace the directory and make the path.

this way you only have to do a single os.path.join

```
Folder = "D:/folder"
Name = ['gadfg5', '546sfdgh']
Ver = [None, 'hhdt5463']
for i in range(len(Name)):
    if Ver[i] is None:
        Ver_element= "asbsda"
    else:
        Ver_element = Ver[i]

    Path = os.path.join(Folder, Name[i], Ver_element)
    print(Path)
```

Output:

```
D:/folder/gadfg5/asbsda
D:/folder/546sfdgh/hhdt5463
```