# How to process double array with break using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, zip

I would like to process an array. Here is my previous question.
[How to process break an array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66580652/11076819)

But I have another case and I refer to that answer, but I still can get my expectation result.
Here is the case

Case 1

```
Folder = "D:\folder"
Name = ['gadfg5', '546sfdgh']
Ver = [None, 'hhdt5463']
Default = {'gadfg5': '6754435'}
```

Case 2

```
Folder = "D:\folder"
Name = ['gadfg5', '546sfdgh']
Ver = [None, 'None']
Default = {'gadfg5': '6754435', '546sfdgh': '98769786'}
```

Case 3

```
Folder = "D:\folder"
Name = ['gadfg5', '546sfdgh']
Ver = [g675436g, 'hhdt5463']
Default = {}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
for dn, dr, key in zip(Name, Ver, Default):
        if dr is None:
            Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, Default[key])
            print("None",Path)
        else:
            Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, dr)
            print("Not None", Path)
```

The output of `CASE 3` is `empty`. But my expectation the output supposed to be:

```
D:\folder\gadfg5\g675436g
D:\folder\546sfdgh\hhdt5463
```

The output of `CASE 2` is correct as my expectation which is:

```
D:\folder\gfg\6754435
D:\folder\546sfdgh\98769786
```

The output of `CASE 1` only returns one path, like this:

```
D:\folder\gadfg5\6754435
```

But my expectation the output supposed to be like this:

```
 D:\folder\gadfg5\6754435
 D:\folder\546sfdgh\hhdt5463
```

Anyone can give me an idea, please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what happens in case one is `Name` and `Ver` has two elements while dictionary `Default` has just one so when you zip them the output will have just one tuple: `('gadfg5', None, 'gadfg5')`

Since the `Default` is a dictionary and its keys are the elements of `Names` we don't have to zip the three of them, instead try:

```
for dn, dr in zip(Name, Ver):
    if dr is None:
        Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, Default[dn])
        print("None", Path)
    else:
        Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, dr)
        print("Not None", Path)
```

The same logic applies to case 3

But there is an issue here let me demonstrate with another scenario, case 4:

**Input:**

```
Folder = "D:\Folder"
Name = ['gadfg5', '546sfdgh']
Ver = [None, 'hhdt5463']
Default = {}
```

Here dict `Default` is empty and `Ver` has a None element. This will throw a Key error at `Default[dn]`. So lets put a check for that too as follows:

```
for dn, dr in zip(Name, Ver):
    if dr is None:
        if dn in Default:  # check if Default contains the key dn
            Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, Default[dn])
            print("None", Path)
        else:
            print('no default path for ', dn)
    else:
        Path = os.path.join(Folder, dn, dr)
        print("Not None", Path)
```

Comment: Hi @Abhi_J if you don’t mind please take a look this https://stackoverflow.com/q/66595850/11076819 thanks a lot