# How to match a string to mapping xml tag using Python?

Tags: python, string, mapping, match

I would like to map a value from an XML file.

```
<Country>
     <number no="2008" info="update">
          <detail name="man1" class="A1\X4">
               <string name="ruth" />
               <string name="amy" />
          </detail>
          <detail name="man2" class="A2">
               <string name="lisa" />
               <string name="graham" />
          </detail>
     </number>
</Country>
```

I need to get the value of the number in here <number no="2008" by mapping with this value class="A1\X4"

T tried this way:

```
stringno = 'A1'
for family in ReadXML.findall('number/detail[@class="{}"]/..'.format(stringno)):
    name = family.get('no')
    print(name)
```

it only works if the `stringno="A1\X4"`. But I need to mapping it if the `stringno = 'A1'`. Is there any matching function in python to solve this problem? maybe `-like` or `-contain`?

Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi what about using an iterative method.

**Full code**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('myXml.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

stringno = 'A1'

for family in root.findall('number'):
    for elem in family:
        if stringno in elem.get('class'):
            print('no: {}, name: {}, class: {}'.format(family.get('no'), elem.get('name'), elem.get('class')))
```

**Input**

> myXml.xml

```xml
<Country>
     <number no="2008" info="update">
          <detail name="man1" class="A1\X4">
               <string name="ruth" />
               <string name="amy" />
          </detail>
          <detail name="man2" class="A2">
               <string name="lisa" />
               <string name="graham" />
          </detail>
     </number>
     <number no="2009" info="update">
          <detail name="man1" class="A1\X5">
               <string name="ruth" />
               <string name="amy" />
          </detail>
          <detail name="man2" class="A3">
               <string name="lisa" />
               <string name="graham" />
          </detail>
     </number>
</Country>
```

**Output**

```
no: 2008, name: man1, class: A1\X4
no: 2009, name: man1, class: A1\X5
```

Comment: hi @Abhi_J I tried it but it return an error `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

Comment: Hi @Cheries I've now included my full code and input file. If you still get the error can you share the the line where the error occurs. Is the structure of your xml file different than mine. I also tried with the input you have provided in the question and it worked as expected.

Comment: hi @Abhi_J I posted my another question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/66666821/11076819
Please help me to check it out if you don't mind. Thank you so much :)